# IDE missing something for functionality?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I am fairly new to coding and am trying to become successful in having a good understanding in web development. I'm running into an issue with a small project and was curious as to what I may be missing. I wonder if its because I'm utilizing methods in my functions for the DOM that may not be in VS Code? Have only started with the add button as I'm trying to make the functionality work.

Have tried changing some syntax but nothing seems to be working

**Code**

```js
function buttons() {
  var in1 = document.getElementById("input1");
  var in2 = document.getElementById("input2");
  var res = document.getElementById("result");
  var add = document.getElementById("button1");

  add.addEventListener("click", function() {
    res.textContent = in1.value + in2.value;
  });
}

buttons()
```

```html
<h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">
<p id="result"></p>
<button id="button1">+</button>
<button id="button2">-</button>
<button id="button3">*</button>
<button id="button4">/</button>
```

Comment: What kind of "IDE feature" are you talking about ? You only provided code so I'm assuming there's something wrong with your code ? You might have to be a little bit clearer, I'm having a hard time understanding what you are asking. In doubt, please refer to the [ask]  section.

Comment: @Yogi Thank you very much that was helpful. I am now running into the issue where my event listening doesn't output the number from the equation. What I mean is every time the button is pushed, it returns the element like this "<input id="result" type="number" readonly="">" and not with a sum or anything. I thought my getelementID is supposed to be a placeholder for a value entered by the user but I guess not?